# Create APK file to Run on Old Android Platforms

Tags: android, apk

Currently i'm developing an Android project on Android `Platform 2.3.3, API Level 10`. I want to build APK file to run my project on `Android 2.0 Device`. How can i do this ? can i run my current APK file on `Android 2.0 Device` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to configure the android:minSdkVersion in the manifest, as explained in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html). This will mean that only the API methods and classes supported by the minimum SDK will be available to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to run your app on different API-levels, Android market supports multiple APKs.

You can upload one apk with minSdkVersion 5 and one with minSdkVersion 10. The last will have to have a higher version code if phones with API-level higher than 5 is going to see this version.

Note, as kgiannakakis said, if you set minSdkVersion to 5 you will not be able to use classes and methods only available in version 10 and up. To avoid this, you can build a stripped down version on level 5 which do not have the same functionality. Or you can use reflection to check if the methods are available at runtime on the current device.